# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC SQL connection error provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I moved my ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project from one computer to another. I did not make any changes in the code. I also moved and restored the database in the same way.

However, I cannot open my project and connect it to SQL Server. I get an error:

> Win32Exception: The network path was not found.
> Unknown location
>
> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I don't think there is a problem with the database because I was able to create a dummy console app and successfully connect to the database and retrieve the data.

What I tried

- I checked the .net versions on both machines
- I checked the version of the package, uninstalled and reinstalled.
  tried different connection strings

I think the problem is in the application because when I tried with the console app I connected successfully

This is my connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "db": "Server=localhost;Database=NIFBase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

Project packages: https://imgur.com/a/4qR0AQ6

Comment: There is clearly not enough info to repro. _"because when I tried with the console app I connected successfully"_ - modern ASP.NET Core apps also are console apps =)

Comment: What other information is needed? I can share the github repo directly.

Comment: You can try but I doubt that this is purely code related.

Comment: Thanks so much.I defined another connection string related to entity framework different from the one in appsettings.json. After you wrote it, I checked the codes one by one and found the problem. Thank you very much again, you helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Provide what you have in SQL server management studio server name to the appsetting.json `Server=SHADOW` (In this example). Also make sure to add
`MultipleActiveResultSets=true` at the endof your connection string.

[image]

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
 "DefaultConnection":"Server=localhost;Database=NIFBase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Comment: I login with localhost when I connecting from sql server management studio

Comment: Then the provided connection string should work make sure to add DefaultConnection in the ConnectionStrings

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried many things but It doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

you are facing connection issues

Create a Database user to access you database
and use this connection string

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=[SQL_SERVER_INSTANCE];Initial Catalog=[DATABASE_NAME];Persist Security Info=False;
        User ID=[DATABASE_USER];Password=[PASSWORD];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
        Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=3600;",
```